# Why Spring @Transactional is successfully rolling back on (SQL insert) but fails when (SQL update) - Multiple Datasources

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, transactions, spring-data-jpa

I have a project that uses Spring Boot & JPA. APIs are exposed using REST.

I have two different databases (Mysql 8) connected and for pooling Hikari has been added. Chained transaction manager has been used for rolling back both DBs in case any one of them failed.

First Issue: If i mark TMSDbConfig as @Primary then no insertion takes place in secondary DB which is UserProfileDbConfig. Only One transactionManager start which is capable to insert in TMSDbConfig.

Second Issue: If i mark UserProfileDbConfig as @Primary then the above problem is solved and now i can insert in both DBs and on insert failure they both are rolling back as well. But when i get the Entity from DB (using findByName())do some changes and persist it back on the failure of second the first one never rollback.

I have tried, @EnableTransactionManagement on MainApp, @ComponentScan @EntityScan

Tried adding annotations @Repository or @Component as well.
Also tried to put the methods in different beans.

Nothing works.

Following are the configurations,
Main:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SingleEntryAuthServiceApp
```

DB Config,

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.mycompany.chainedtransactionmanager.repository.db2",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "db2EntityManagerFactory", transactionManagerRef = "db2PlatformTransactionManager")
public class UserProfileDbConfig {

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "db2DataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.userprofile-datasource")
    public DataSource db2DataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "db2EntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean db2EntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        return builder
                .dataSource(db2DataSource())
                .packages("com.mycompany.chainedtransactionmanager.model.db2")
                .persistenceUnit("db2")
                .build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "db2PlatformTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager db2PlatformTransactionManager(EntityManagerFactory db2EntityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(db2EntityManagerFactory);
    }
}
```

Another DB Config,

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.mycompany.chainedtransactionmanager.repository.pgsql",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "pgsqlEntityManagerFactory", transactionManagerRef = "pgsqlPlatformTransactionManager")
public class TMSDbConfig {


    @Bean(name = "pgsqlDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.tms-datasource")
    public DataSource pgsqlDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }


    @Bean(name = "pgsqlEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean 
        pgsqlEntityManagerFactory(@Qualifier("pgsqlDataSource") DataSource 
        pgsqlDataSource, EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        return builder
                .dataSource(pgsqlDataSource)
                .packages("com.mycompany.chainedtransactionmanager.model.pgsql")
                .persistenceUnit("pgsql")
                .build();
    }


    @Bean(name = "pgsqlPlatformTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager pgsqlPlatformTransactionManager(@Qualifier("pgsqlEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory pgsqlEntityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(pgsqlEntityManagerFactory);
    }
}
```

ChainedTransactionManager,

```
@Configuration
public class TransactionManagerConfig {

    @Bean(name = "chainedTransactionManager")
    public ChainedTransactionManager transactionManager(
            @Qualifier("db2PlatformTransactionManager") PlatformTransactionManager db2PlatformTransactionManager,
            @Qualifier("pgsqlPlatformTransactionManager") PlatformTransactionManager pgsqlPlatformTransactionManager) {
        return new ChainedTransactionManager(db2PlatformTransactionManager,
                pgsqlPlatformTransactionManager);
    }
}
```

Service Layer Insert Code, Successfully Rolling Back,

```
@Override
@Transactional(value = "chainedTransactionManager", rollbackFor = {Exception.class}, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void saveService() {
    try {
        {//Insert code..


            DB2Test1 SecTable = new DB2Test1();
            SecTable.setName("LongTextToCreateSqlError");
            db2Repo.save(SecTable);

            DB1Test1 firstTable = new DB1Test1();
            firstTable.setName("acceptedText");
            db1Repo.save(firstTable);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
```

Service Layer Update Code, Failed Rolling Back,

```
@Override
    @Transactional(value = "chainedTransactionManager", rollbackFor = {Exception.class}, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void saveService() {
try {
    DB2Test1 SecTable = db2Repo.findByName("Jhon");
    SecTable.setName("LongTextToCreateFailed");

    try {
        db2Repo.save(SecTable);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }
    DB1Test1 firstTable =  db1Repo.findByName("Jhon");
    firstTable.setName("AcceptedText");
    try {
        db1Repo.save(firstTable);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw e;
}
}
```

In the logs i can see that in case of Insert the entityManager didnt closed until both db operation got success,

but in case of update after running the first update Query the entityManager closed.
I am unable to understand the behavior,
Insert case is successfully rolling back but on update its not rolling back. If its realated with managed beans then what is the difference between insert code and update code.

Thanks a lot Greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

Found a Solution, May be it will save couple of days for someone searching for this,

I switched from JPA simple .save() method to .saveAndFlush() and all the test cases have been passed either both persists in DB or both rollback.

Cheers!

Comment: Hi, thats happens because the synchronization of the hibernate session with the DB (flush) doesnt occurs whenever you call save() https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core.old/reference/en/html/objectstate-flushing.html